# How to use a hash value defined in my program in a another perl one-liner program?

Tags: perl, hash

I am using Perl on Windows with Eclipse IDE.
What I have already done is, that I have parsed a text file and extracted the contents I need, into a `%hash`.
And finally, my `%hash "Key"` contains function names and `%hash "Value"` contains the corresponding function definition.

Now, my query is, Can I used my`%hash "Values"` in a `PERL` one-liner(which I am running at the end of the same program) ?

If Yes, then I have tried the following, and it doesn't seem to work:

`perl -pi.bak -e "if(! /#/){s/ PERFORM ([\\w-]+)\.?/qq(#  PERFORM \$1\n). \$hash{\$1}/ge}" TestFinal.txt`;

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a larger perl script and in that you want to *se backticks to call a perl one-liner to edit a file? Using system calls is almost never the best solution. And in this case twice as tricky. If I were you I would just open the files manually.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are usually only stored in memory, to keep a variable between different instances of Perl, you will need some kind of "persistence".

You can use Data::Dumper, Storable, DBM::Deep, or any other of a number of mechanisms.

**Edit:**

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# this module can dump a variable in "do"-able format
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
  john => 'doe',
  tarzan => 'jane',
);

open my $fh, '>', 'data' or die "cannot open data file";
print $fh Dumper \%hash;
```

One liner:

```
perl -e '%hash = do "data" or die "cannot load data"; # do stuff with %hash'
```

Comment: Errm.. being a newbie to Perl, I will now first read how to use the them. :)  Any other way by chance..? Since Perl always have more than one way to do it. :)

Comment: my $tempVar= %hash; my $storedValues = freeze( $megalith ); `perl -pi.bak -e "if(! /#/){s/ PERFORM ([\\w-]+)\.?/qq(# PERFORM \$1\n). \$storedValues{\$1}/ge}" TestFinal.txt`; Then I am using the storedValues in the one-line..Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: you need to then `thaw` the stored data into the one-liner.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... after thaw-ing the stored value also. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @faezshingeri, the data must be imported into your one-liner. I have added an example using the most basic mechanism, [`Data::Dumper`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) for storage and [`do EXPR`](http://p3rl.org/do) to load the data from the storage.